# What does onclick='mycheck("+i+")' do?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and would appreciate your explanation on this code.

I was provided with the below code as an example and needed to make some changes
to it but I'm unsure what `onclick='mycheck("+i+")'` is meant to do.

I know its calling the function `mycheck()` but not sure what `+i+` in parameter is meant for.

This is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x=new Array(10);
    var myseat="";

    function seatgen()
    {
        for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
        {
            myseat+="<img src='seat_avail.png' onclick='mycheck("+i+")'>";         
            x[i]="available";
        }
        document.getElementById("seathere").innerHTML=myseat;
    }

    function mycheck(k)
    {
        if(x[k]=="available")
            {alert("available")}
        else
            {alert("Not available");}
        }
</script>
```

Comment: +i+ in your above code is meant to pass the value of " i " to the javascript method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sets up an event handler so that when the element is clicked, it calls the `myclick` function with the value `i`.

The `img` tags end up looking like this:

```
<img src='seat_avail.png' onclick='mycheck(0)'>
<img src='seat_avail.png' onclick='mycheck(1)'>
<img src='seat_avail.png' onclick='mycheck(2)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

It inserts i into the output string.

For example, on iteration #0, it will output:
`<img src='seat_avail.png' onclick='mycheck(0)'>;` and call `mycheck` with `0` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it generates seats so for every iteration of the loop clicking a image would execute the mycheck function with another parameter.

Please google about using loops in javascript to fully understand the problem. I.e. you can refer to [Loops on w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)